# Use Stimulsoft for reporting data in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stimulsoft

when i was work with `Windows Form Application C#` .For reporting use [Stimulsoft](http://www.stimulsoft.com) and use this code for showing view report data.

```
StiReport rpt2 = new StiReport();
rpt2.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\RPT\\RPTListPoorsantNamayandeh.mrt");

rpt2.Compile();
rpt2["namayandeh"] = comboPoorsantNamayandeh.Text;
rpt2["StTarikh"] = StTarikh;
rpt2["EnTarikh"] = EnTarikh;
rpt2["tarikhGozaresh"] = tarikhGozaresh;
rpt2["GozareshCode"] = GozareshCode;
rpt2.RegData(dtRPTPoorsant);
rpt2.Render();
rpt2.Show();
```

the above code is true and now i'm working with Asp.net core , for reporting data i want use [Stimulsoft](http://www.stimulsoft.com).In the example below show reporting file but i don't no how can i send DataSet or DataTable or Models to mrt file

Controller :

```
 public IActionResult GetReport()
        {          
            string reportString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Reoprt\\ParametersSelectingCountry.mrt");
            return StiNetCoreViewer.GetReportResult(this, reportString);
        }

        public IActionResult ViewerEvent()
        {
            return StiNetCoreViewer.ViewerEventResult(this);
        }
```

index.chstml

```
@using Stimulsoft.Report.NetCore
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiNetCoreViewer("NetCoreViewver1",new StiNetCoreViewerOptions()
{
    Actions =
    {
        GetReport = "GetReport",
        ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- .NET Core 1.x doesn't support `DataTable`s or `DataSet`s. They will be added in v2.x.
- `RegData` accepts a `DataTable`. Use [RegBusinessObject](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1803/%DA%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF%DB%8C-%DA%AF%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B2-business-objects-%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%86%D8%AF-list-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%B7-stimulsoft) to pass a list.

Comment: This link for asp.net mvc. but i don't know how to do it in asp.net core 1.1

Comment: How can i use stimulsoft license.key in asp.net core 2?